# Is there any typesafe way to refer to Queues in Apex?

Tags: apex, queue, type

Let's say I have a Queue named "My Queue 123" with a Developer Name of "My_Queue_123", is there any typesafe way to refer to it in Apex?

Or can I only pass it around as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike many features, such as field sets and other metadata API names, there's no such thing for queues (which are, of course, Group objects). As usual in these cases, consider using a static constant (`public static final String GROUPNAME = 'whatever'`), custom metadata, or custom label to refer to the group consistently.

Comment: Didn't think so, but thought to check.  Thanks.  :-)